# A strictly convex function on $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

$p(t)=\begin{cases}
       t\log{t}-t &\quad\text{if} \quad t>0\\
       0 &\quad\text{if} \quad t=0 \\
      +\infty &\quad\text{otherwise.} \\ 
     \end{cases}$

Now we define the function on $\mathbb{R^n}$ , $f(x)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}p(x_i)$.

We want to prove that $f$ is strictly convex on $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Comment: $p(t)=+\infty$ has no meaning

Comment: @Martigan What do you mean?

Comment: @BigbearZzz $\infty$ is not a number, and it is no value that a function can take. You should probably define your function so that it is only defined on $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: @Martigan It's common in convex analysis to let the range of a convex function be the extended real number system $\Bbb R\cup \{\infty\}$.

Comment: @Martigan Think of $p$ as defining the set $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : p(x) \le y\}$ then $p$ is convex iff this set is convex. Having $p$ be $+ \infty$ at some points fits in perfectly.

Comment: @Martigan you might find some searches on the topic "extended real valued functions" helpful here.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I know what it is. It always shocks me to see $f(x)=+\infty$. To me there is a difference between a function mapping the extended real numbers and a function taking the VALUE of something which, even in that context, are not numbers...

Comment: Fair enough. but it is an incredibly useful  and widely used convention in this space (convex analysis and optimization). It's not going away, and I'm glad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the sum of strictly convex functions is strictly convex (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325952/sum-of-strictly-convex-and-convex-functions)), it suffices to prove that $p$ is convex. Clearly $p$ is convex on $(0,\infty)$, as the second derivative is strictly positive.

The definition of strict convexity is that
$p(\lambda a + (1-\lambda)b) < \lambda p(a) + (1-\lambda)p(b)$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ ($a \neq b$) and for all $0<\lambda<1$. Assume wlog that $a<b$. If $a<0$ or $a>0$, the condition is clearly satisfied.

What remains is proving:
$$p(\lambda 0 + (1-\lambda)b) < \lambda p(0) + (1-\lambda)p(b)$$
for $b>0$ and $0<\lambda<1$. That is:
$$p((1-\lambda)b) < (1-\lambda)p(b)$$
or
$$(1-\lambda)b\log((1-\lambda)b) < (1-\lambda)b \log(b)$$
Since $(1-\lambda)b > 0$, this simplifies to $\log((1-\lambda)b) < \log(b)$, which is true since the logarithm is strictly increasing.

Comment: I agree. thank you